# How to align elements using ConstraintLayout Flow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I am using ConstraintLayout Flow want to create layout like below[image]

**But not able to achieve above using ConstraintLayout Flow my layout looks like below**

[image]

Below is my code

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgAiport"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tvDateLbl,tvTimeLbl,tvAirlineLbl,tvDate,tvTime,imgAirlineLogo"
        app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:flow_maxElementsWrap="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

How to correctly align elements using ConstraintLayout Flow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only options here is to make all these `TextView's` to one width size with text gravity to the start.

Comment: hey thanks for the clue removed wrap_content width from all childs and kept width 0dp working as expected now. Can you make change in your answer so that I can accept it